# Large Number Limit Extravaganza

Tags: python, performance, primes, mathematics

I am writing a program that computes

$$n-n \cdot \left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{p_i})\right)$$

which is rewritten in my code as:

$$\left(1-\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\frac{1}{p_i})\right)\right) \cdot n$$

There are lots of primes involved here especially as \$n\$ gets larger and larger. I do not want to use Atkin's method for generating them since my teacher and I will probably lose oversight as to what is going on, but would still like to optimize my algorithm for speed and accuracy (not sure if the latter can be better).

```
i = 0
j = 3
old = 1.0
primes = [2]
while True:
    if (j>240000): break
    cont = True
    enumerator = 0
    for e in primes:
        if j%e==0: cont = False
        if enumerator>=len(primes)/2 + 1: break
        enumerator += 1
    if cont: primes.append(j)   
    j+=2
#print primes

while True:
    if (i>len(primes)-1): break
    old = old * (1 - 1.0/primes[i])
    print old
    i+=1;
primeslessthan = j-1
amta = 1-old

print "The convergence: " + str(primeslessthan)
print "All the way up to the number: " + str(amta)
print "The amount of active inhibitors are: " + str((1-amta)*primeslessthan)
```

I am open to multithreading, and to translating this to a different language like C++, but do not know what optimizations I could make there either.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: In your code you seem to calculate `n*(1 - Pi(1 - 1/p))`, instead of `n*(1 - Pi(1 - p))`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your method of generating primes is horribly slow. Running your code takes on the order of 5 minutes on my machine.

Consider as an alternative a [prime sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Prime_sieves), even a simple one like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) will do (you don't need to go full Atkinson on it):

```
def prime_sieve(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False

    for i, isprime in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            for n in xrange(i * i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prod = 1
    for p in prime_sieve(240000):
        prod *= (1 - 1.0 / p)
        print prod
    primes_less_than = p - 1
    amta = 1 - prod

    print "The convergence:", primes_less_than
    print "All the way up to the number:", amta
    print "The amount of active inhibitors are:", prod * primes_less_than
```

This runs in less than a second.

**Accuracy**

In your question you said you want to calculate $$n \cdot \left(1-\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i)\right)\right)$$ But in your code you implemented $$n \cdot \left(1-\left(\prod_{i=1}^n(1-1/p_i)\right)\right)$$.

You do `amta = 1 -old` and then later `(1 - amta) * primeslessthan`. Here you are needlessly loosing precision, because `1 - (1 - x) != x` due to floating point precision. Better use `old` directly in the output.

**Review:**
Python has an official style-guide, which programmers are encouraged to follow, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Your code violates it in the following points:

1. Always put the expression after an `if` in a new line
2. Use spaces around operators
3. Use `lower_case` names for variables and functions
4. `old` is a bad name for a variable, `amta` even worse

In addition, the following are discouraged for iterating in python:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, ...]

for i in range(len(l)):
    print l[i]

i = 0
while True:
    if i > len(l) - 1:
        break
    print l[i]
    i += 1
```

Just use this simple syntax:

```
for x in l:
    print x
```

Note that the `if` does not need any parenthesis.

Finally, the `print` statement can take multiple expressions, separated by commas. Alternatively, you can use `str.format`:

```
print "The convergence: {}".format(primeslessthan)
print "All the way up to the number: {}".format(amta)
print "The amount of active inhibitors are: {}".format((1 - amta) * primeslessthan)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the "[True]" syntax you were using in line 2?

Comment: @LinusRastegar `[True]` is a list with one element and that element is the value `True`. In addition, `[True] * 3 == [True, True, True]`. This also works e.g. with strings, `"a" * 3 == "aaa"`.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification! I was able to run the code and of course everything runs much faster now! I am now trying to test with limit = 1 billion. Is there some multithreading trick I could use to make the program run faster?

Comment: Probably not with a sieve, because you need to mark off all multiples of prime numbers off as being composite, this won't work in parallel. One thing you could do is write the primes to a file. For some bound this might be faster than calculating them all, because increasing the `limit` gives not linear increase in runtime.

Comment: @LinusRastegar For all primes up to 1,000,000,000, you probably want to comment out the `print`, though.

Comment: @SweekarRajChhetri Let's discuss this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88414/discussion-between-graipher-and-sweekar-raj-chhetri)